# What do you call a sole that's not "filled"?

Tags: word-request

[image]

The shoes has a sole with a lot of gaps unlike most shoes that have a sole that's filled. What the adjective for saying there's no gap or empty space, and what's the adjective for saying the exact opposite?

For example:

> The sole of my shoe was ___.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's general, because it applies to more than just soles of shoes, I would use the word [**hollow**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hollow#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    2 : having an unfilled or hollowed-out space
>   // within a *hollow* tree

In other words:

> The sole of my shoe was *hollow*.

Comment: A hollow sole would imply that there isn't a center layer of the shoe to most people, not that the sole has treads.

Comment: I agree with pboss3010, a hollow sole implies there isn't a filling inside the sole.

Answer (score 3):

I would use "tread."

> The soles of my shoes had deep treads molded into them.

Edit: and I would use the word "smooth" for not-filled.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: I like this answer. As an adjective, one could use _treaded_ (or _deeply-treaded_, if need be).

Answer (score 3):

Within the footwear industry itself, this is called a **lug tread**. One of the [definitions of **lug**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lug) is "a ridge (as on the bottom of a shoe) to increase traction."

However, while you will find the phrase "lug tread" used in customer-facing advertisements (for example, [here](https://blackwellshoes.com/products/womens-colette-black) is an ad for a "Women's genuine leather lace-up boot with a lug tread rubber sole"), I would not say that it's commonly used in everyday speech.  More frequently you'd hear people saying that a shoe has a **deep tread** or a **deep-cut tread**.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the currently-accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

An appropriate word could be “reticulated”.

> **reticulate** (*verb*) divide or mark (something) in such a way as to resemble a net or network: *the numerous canals and branches of the river reticulate the plain*. (Oxford)

Comment: Cool word, but, when applied to footwear, _reituclated_ typically refers to the breathable fabric of the shoe material, not to the pattern on the sole. (See the [reticulated Nike Zoom](https://shopee.com.my/Nike-Zoom-Rival-Fly-8-Reticulated-Running-Shoes-Red-i.114322501.2102170113), e.g.)